# Zend Form and Doctrine with multiple Entities

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I have some troubles with Zend Form and Doctrine when the form itself should handle more than one Entity.

```
categories
-- id
-- name

category_translations
-- id
-- locale
-- field1
-- field2
-- category_id
```

So it's basically a simple one-to-many relation. I've created two Doctrine Entities and also two Form Fieldsets (as suggested in the manual). My form looks as follow:

http://oi65.tinypic.com/2rm8oq0.jpg

I already read about hydrators etc. but right now i've no idea how to save and populate a form with more than one entity. Am i missing something here or is there really no way to prevent ugly workarounds?

With one entity, the population is easy and works great (for add and update). In my controller:

```
$entityManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
$hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager);
$category = new \Application\Model\Category();
$form->setHydrator($hydrator);
$form->setObject($category);
$form->bind($category);
```

Thanks :)!

Comment: Can you explain me the relationship with Symfony so I can try to help?

Comment: @Rvanlaak - Zend is a framework similar to Symfony with it's own form component as well as support for Doctrine.  So it's doubtful that the poster has a great deal of Symfony knowledge.  Which is perhaps a bit sad because this sort of thing is trivial in Symfony.  I'm guessing it is easy in Zend as well but would need to check the docs.

Comment: Yes, i have to implement this with Doctrine and Zend Framework. Do you have a link for me on how this is handled in Symfony? Maybe that helps...

Comment: Doubt if it will help as the components are very different but here you go: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html

Comment: I believe you need to use Zend\Form\Fieldset and set the hydrator and object (entity) in there and add it to your form.  I've personally not done this yet.